# T-SQL Calculating Time Quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Person      Beginning            Ending               Length
1           1/1/2022 12:25:00    1/1/2022 13:05:00    2400
```

I would like to parse this record across quarter buckets and the length spent in each quarter bucket.

```
Person      Beginning            Ending               Length      Bucket 
1           1/1/2022 12:25:00    1/1/2022 13:05:00    300         12:15     
1           1/1/2022 12:25:00    1/1/2022 13:05:00    900         12:30 
1           1/1/2022 12:25:00    1/1/2022 13:05:00    900         12:45 
1           1/1/2022 12:25:00    1/1/2022 13:05:00    300         13:00
```

Comment: The `End` is *after* the `Start` here. should `1:05:00` really be `13:05:00`? If you have stored it as `1:05:00` then your `End` is ~11 hours *before* your `Start`.

Comment: Also `End` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and `Start` a [Future Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#future-keywords); both are poor choices for object names, as they will likely need to be delimit identified. Ideally avoid keywords for object names.

Comment: Fixed those now

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the Future Keyword ... I got kick knowing they would think to publish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option ... BRUTE FORCE

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ddf5a659746c2c286abafc7e287aca2b)**

```
Select A.Person
      ,A.[Begining]
      ,A.[Ending]
      ,B.[Length]
      ,Bucket = left(convert(varchar(10),Bucket,8),5)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select [Length] = sum(1)
                      ,Bucket  
                  From (Select Top (datediff(SECOND,[Begining],[Ending])) D=dateadd(SECOND,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),[Begining]) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 ) B1
                  Cross Apply ( values (dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,D) / 15 ) * 15,0)  ) ) C(Bucket)
                  Group By Bucket
             ) B
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: I see that it works but I do not see fully how it works. Could you explain please?

Comment: @Concept The 1st CROSS APPLY simply generates N records (1 per second) .  The 2nd CROSS APPLY generates the BUCKET.   Then it becomes a small matter to aggregate by BUCKET.    Honestly I don't know if Larnu's is more performat or not.

Comment: @Concept Just for fun, here we remove the aggregation and show a little more detail.   Note you get 2,400 records  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=27e9adb8bd977425551af47af5b25ef9

Comment: "Simplification" (in that it avoids the cross join and aggregation, replacing it with maths) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b6cdd8c9ad07b6fd513c553d61fec407

Comment: @MatBailie Not sure I'd agree with the term "Simplification", but certainly MOST IMPRESSIVE

Comment: Same as your answer, to create the rows for each bucket. But, then recognises that all buckets are 15mins except the first and last; so if the bucket is the first deduct a bit, and if it's the last deduct a different bit.

Comment: @MatBailie I get it.   I was simply not bright enough to think of it that way.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use some "magic" dates and a Tally. This isn't particularly pretty, but looks like this:

```sql
SELECT V.Person,
       V.[Start],
       V.[End],
       V.Length,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND,CASE WHEN V.[Start] > R.BucketStart THEN V.[Start] ELSE R.BucketStart END, CASE WHEN V.[End] < R.BucketEnd THEN V.[End] ELSE R.BucketEnd END) AS Length
FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'1/1/2022 12:25:00',103),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'1/1/2022 13:05:00',103),2400))V(Person, [Start], [End], Length)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,[Start])/15)*15,0),DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,[End])/15)*15,0)))B(StartBucket,EndBucket)
     CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,B.StartBucket,B.EndBucket) / 15,0) T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MINUTE,T.I*15,B.StartBucket),DATEADD(MINUTE,(T.I+1)*15,B.StartBucket)))R(BucketStart,BucketEnd);
```

Note the use of the function `Tally`, which has the following definition:

```sql
CREATE   FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@End bigint, @StartAtOne bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @StartAtOne = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (@End)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7, N N8)
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally;
GO
```

On the next version of SQL Server (2022) then it's actually easier, as you have access to `DATE_BUCKET`, and also `GENERATE_SERIES` (though I don't use `GENERATE_SERIES` here for intentionally undisclosed reasons).

```sql
SELECT V.Person,
       V.[Start],
       V.[End],
       V.Length,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND,CASE WHEN V.[Start] > R.BucketStart THEN V.[Start] ELSE R.BucketStart END, CASE WHEN V.[End] < R.BucketEnd THEN V.[End] ELSE R.BucketEnd END) AS Length,
       CONVERT(time(0),R.BucketStart) AS Bucket
FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'1/1/2022 12:25:00',103),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'1/1/2022 13:05:00',103),2400))V(Person, [Start], [End], Length)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATE_BUCKET(MINUTE, 15, V.[Start]),DATE_BUCKET(MINUTE, 15, V.[End])))B(StartBucket,EndBucket)
     CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,B.StartBucket,B.EndBucket)/15,0) T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MINUTE,T.I*15,B.StartBucket),DATEADD(MINUTE,(T.I+1)*15,B.StartBucket)))R(BucketStart,BucketEnd);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing but I have not tried it. I prefer to try without using a function.

Comment: You could use an inline tally if you prefer, @Concept , but a function makes more sense here.